# Youtube API Call for user likes/favorites

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

Hey does anyone know how to make a call to youtube with PHP so I can get a user's likes or favorites returned? preferably with data about each video. I can't seem to find a way to do it anywhere. Let me know please.

Answer (score 2):

First result on google is fairly in depth and includes everything you'll need
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-youtubeapi/